# Print a table in pairs

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm trying to use `in pairs` inside a function but it doesn't work, it just prints the first row (key). This is my code:

```
set = {1,2,3,4};
unset = {5,6,7,8};

    function listen(ftype)
        if (ftype == [[~]]) then
            for num,str in pairs(set) do
                return str;
            end
        end
        if (ftype == [[$]]) then
            for num,str in pairs(unset) do
                return str;
            end
        end
    end

    print(listen([[~]])..[[ =:= ]]..listen([[$]]));
```

If I do something like this..

```
for num,str in pairs(unset) do
    print(str);
end
```

It works like a charm. That’s exactly what I want but inside a function.

Comment: What output did you expect exactly?

Comment: 1 =:= 5 <BREAK>
2 =:= 6 <BREAK>
3 =:= 7 <BREAK>
4 =:= 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function can't return multiple times.  Putting an unconditional `return` inside a loop is nonsensical - it will never get to the second iteration of the loop.

You are essentially trying to return multiple values from the function.  Lua supports that; you could, for instance, just  `return 1,2,3,4`.  For an unknown number of return values, you can build them up in a table and call `unpack` on it, like so:

```
function listen(ftype)
    local result = {}
    local num, str
    if (ftype == [[~]]) then
        for num,str in pairs(set) do
            table.insert(result, str)
        end
    elseif (ftype == [[$]]) then
        for num,str in pairs(unset) do
            table.insert(result, str)
        end
    end
    return unpack(result)
end
```

But since your results are already in a couple tables, it would be silly to reconstruct them that way.  You can just unpack the originals:

```
function listen(ftype)
    if (ftype == [[~]]) then
        return unpack(set)
    elseif (ftype == [[$]]) then
        return unpack(unset)
    end
end
```

Great.  But when you put the function call into an expression like your `print` statement, it will only return the first value, which puts you back where you started.

So to print out your pairs, you can't avoid having to either:

1) do some iteration *outside* the function
or
2) do the actual printing *inside* the function

The cleanest solution is probably a custom iterator, as suggested by @YuHao.

Comment: Adding a comment so you'll notice that I've edited my answer significantly; I hope the additional information is helpful.  Thanks for accepting it, but I think @YuHao's is more useful to you.

Answer (score 7):

You can build your own iterator:

```
function double_pair(t1, t2)
    local i = 0
    return function() i = i + 1
               return t1[i] and t1[i] .. " =:= " .. t2[i] 
           end
end
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
for str in double_pair(set, unset) do
    print(str)
end
```

Output:

```
1 =:= 5
2 =:= 6
3 =:= 7
4 =:= 8
```

Note that you don't need semicolons to end your statement, unless the statements are in one line and you want to make them clear. And `[[ =:= ]]` is usually used to build long multi-line strings, normally we choose to use double quote `" =:= "` or single quote `' =:= '`.